# why does my html a tag not work with css float: right?

Tags: html, css

I have a bilingual site made with ruby on rails and in the top right corner is a link to the English version and Spanish version. I have 2 layouts, one for each language. Both use the same class. Here is the html

```
<a class="language" href="home">ENGLISH</a>
```

and the css:

```
.language {
  float:right;
  color: white
}
```

My problem is that without css applied the links work fine. When I apply css the word ENGLISH appears on the screan but just as normal text and not a link. I tried commenting out `float:right;` and again the link works but the word is in the middle of the screen because the body has `text-align` set to justify.  I have also tried using `text-align: right;` in stead of `float: right` and this seems to have no effect.  What is happening?

Comment: Well, with the code you have given, it works. [See](https://jsfiddle.net/sanky6/3no11d4y/1/).

Comment: This is true. A working example right here.
https://jsfiddle.net/85z5hg38/
There must be something else in your HTML or CSS that is conflicting with this class or with `a` tags.

Comment: @Sankarsh Makam @Naltroc. That is strange. without the float the link works but obviously wont be in the right place. why isn't the `text-align` property working? is there any othere way to get the link into the top right corner without using `float`?

Comment: `right: 0;` That would work wouldn't it? I'll expand in an answer...

Comment: Provide code that can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

your codes should work fine. maybe your css file is overridden by another css
however, you can try the inline styling approach

```
<a href="home" class="language" style="float:right; color:white;">ENGLISH</a>
```

and it should work fine

Comment: could the body css be overriding it with text align set to justify?

Comment: try clearing your cache and also try it in different browser as well